# How to write a file in azure function app in python?

Tags: python, pandas, azure-functions

I am creating a azure function. This function locally have a csv file. I read it via given code

```
csv = f'{context.function_directory}/new_csv.csv'
df=pd.read_csv(csv)
```

after reading the data, I want to make some changes to this csv (like adding some columns). Please suggest some code how can I write this updated csv/dataframe in same directory and with the same name.

Comment: make the changes and then write the `csv` back to the server with `to_csv()`.

Answer (score 0):

you just have to write back to the same file (or a new file)...

```py
csv = f'{context.function_directory}/new_csv.csv'
df=pd.read_csv(csv)

# make edits to the dataframe

make a new csv or write to existing csv

df.to_csv()
```

Here is a link:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Comment: No, this doesn't work in azure

Comment: this is just a standard process. what error message do you get ?